# At what age can one live alone (in Greece)?

Tags: minor, age

In Greece, how old do you have to be to move out and live alone (by which I mean that you could buy your own home, or even move to another country for the rest of your life)?

Comment: The age of majority in Greece is 18 years. In most jurisdictions, it's possible for minors to be emancipated, for example by marriage or by a court order.  This may also be the case in Greece.